# How can I make this JavaScript Timer function properly?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, timer, coding-style

I am trying to make a timer using JavaScript. The problem is, I can't get the timer to stop when it reaches 0. I have tried using `return` and `if` statements, but nothing seems to be working. Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this?

```
<input type="text" id="minutes" style="width:30px;text-align:center" maxlength="2" placeholder="00">
<span>:</span>
<input type="text" id="seconds" style="width:30px;text-align:center" maxlength="2" placeholder="00">
<button onclick="timer()">Set</button>

<script>
//This prototype correctly uses the modulus function when dealing with negative numbers.
Number.prototype.mod = function (m) {
    return ((this % m) + m) % m
}

function timer() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes').value //Value of minutes box.
    var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds').value //Value of seconds box.
    var initial = seconds * 1000 //Amount of seconds (converted to milliseconds) initially set.
    var milliseconds = (minutes * 60000) + (seconds * 1000) //Total amount of milliseconds set.

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("Time's up!")
    }, milliseconds) //Display a message when the set time is up.

    /*\Decreases the minute by one after the initially set amount of seconds have passed.
    |*|Then, clears the interval and sets a new one to decrease the minute every 60 seconds.
    \*/
    test = setInterval(function () {
        minutes--;
        document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
        clearInterval(test)
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes--;
            document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes
        }, 60000)
    }, initial)

    //Seconds are set to decrease by one every 1000 milliseconds, then be displayed in the seconds box.
    setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds.mod(60)
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the code that attempts to stop the timers?

Comment: @Pointy It's no longer there. I tried several things, but none of them worked for reasons which I have already figured out. I am just looking for a suggestion of how it _could_ be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four different timer functions (setTimer and two setIntervals) when you only need one. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AgCY/1)

```
function timer() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes').value //Value of minutes box.
    var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds').value //Value of seconds box.
    var intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;
        }
        document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
        document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds;
        if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            alert("Time's up!");
            clearInterval(intervalTimer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

In general, you need to make sure every `setInterval` is given a name (`var x = setInterval...`) and cleared later on (`clearInterval(x)`). You could have separate timers (one for the minutes which starts after the given number of seconds then repeats every 60 seconds, one for seconds, and one to display the message) if you really want to for some reason, as long as you clear all of the interval timers once the countdown reaches zero.

Using two timers might make sense, however. This would make sure that the Time's up message really appears when it's supposed to, even if there is any imprecision in the interval timer.

```
function timer() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes').value,
        seconds = document.getElementById('seconds').value,
        intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;
        }
        document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
        document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds;
    }, 1000);
    setTimer(function () {
        alert("Time's up!");
        clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    }, minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: First run your timer in seconds and on-complete, run it again by minutes, then your timer in running in minus. :p

Answer (score 1):

I made improvements to Stuart's answer: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6qdS/)

Basically the same thing, except it works properly:

```
function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}
var intervalTimer;
function timer() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes').value //Value of minutes box.
    var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds').value //Value of seconds box.
    intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds += 60;
            minutes--;
        }
        if (minutes < 0) {
            alert("Time's up!");
            clearTimer();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
            document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not a great javascript guy, but maybe this will help. i made this in typescript http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

but i would do timing different and use the javascript date object  and calculate differences. This is a simple example of how i would start to create a time (without the date object)

javascript

```
var Timer = (function () {
    function Timer(time) {
        this.accuracy = 1000;
        this.time = time;
    }
    Timer.prototype.run = function (button) {
        var _this = this;
        this.time -= 1; //this is inaccurate, for accurate time use the date objects and calculate the difference.

        //http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp
        button.textContent = this.time.toString();
        if (this.time > 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                return _this.run(button);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
    return Timer;
})();

var time = new Timer(10);
var button = document.createElement('button');
time.run(button);

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

typescript(in case you wonder)

```
class Timer {
    accuracy = 1000;//update every second
    time: number;
    constructor(time: number) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    run(button: HTMLButtonElement) {
        this.time -=1;//this is inaccurate, for accurate time use the date objects and calculate the difference.
        //http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp
        button.textContent = this.time.toString();
        if(this.time > 0)
        {
            setTimeout(()=> this.run(button),1000);
        }
    }
}

var time = new Timer(10)
var button = document.createElement('button');
time.run(button);

document.body.appendChild(button);
```